# Send a json with a multiline string instead of \n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string with \n as a join result:

```
my_var = ['name','phone','age'].join("\n")
```

I will send this string in the body of a post as a Json:

```
def body
  { "str": my_var }
end
```

I want to send the var in multiple lines instead of sending the \n like this:

```
"name\nphone\nage"
```

EDIT: 
I am sending this string joined with \n to another dev team as a json in the body of my post request to their uri. But they don't want to receive a string with \n and replace or translate there. They want to recieve in multiple lines.

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: good point, this is a info i can use to prove my point

Answer (score 0):

You can use different separator and then, on receive, separate lines from whole string based on that delimiter using

`my_delimiter = '\n'` or `my_delimiter = ';'`

`lines = my_var.split(my_delimiter)`.

Or you could iterate over `['name','phone','age']` and add them as separate json elements.

If this doesn't help, then please clarify your question.

Comment: the reciever wants to recieve a json like this: 
{ "content":  "name
phone
age"
}
in multiple lines instead of \n

Comment: Then the receiver will parse multiline string base on `\n` separator, or, in Windows, on `\r\n` separator. You can also consider assigning array to your key (`"str"`), so you would get a json like this `{ "content" : [ "name" , "phone" , "age" ] }`. Which could be interpreted as array of lines. If you don't have accect to the receiving end and don't know how exactly to format json, try different ways to find out which works.

Answer (score 0):

They *are* receiving multiple lines, depending on their OS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

```
2.1.10 :001 > my_var = ['name','phone','age'].join("\n")
 => "name\nphone\nage" 
2.1.10 :002 > puts my_var
name
phone
age
 => nil 
2.1.10 :003 > my_var.to_json
 => "\"name\\nphone\\nage\"" 
2.1.10 :004 > puts my_var.to_json
"name\nphone\nage"
 => nil 
2.1.10 :005 >
```

The text you're sending them contains instructions on where a line break is (i.e. the \n character).  The graphical display of it is up to their end.

Comment: I agree, the problem is that I noticed that they are a little slow to understand, so I tried a way to do this...But I realized now that a Json with a single field in multiple lines is not even a valid json. This is a info that I can show to them

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected format of the JSON. You should not be including a new line in the values, but using the '\n' character.

```
json = { text: ['name','phone','age'].join("\n") }.to_json
puts JSON.parse( json )['text']
```

you can see the parse is parsing it correctly.

```
pry(main)> puts JSON.parse( json )['text']
name
phone
age
=> nil
```